# How to find PathAuto state?

Tags: path-aliases

I am trying to put together a list of content on the site that has the PathAuto setting still checked so it will update when the title of the page is changed. Can't seem to find where this would be stored in the database.

Just wondering if it is possible to find what Pathauto state is set for each entity on my site. I know in previous versions of Drupal there was a database table called pathauto_state that would show Entity Type, Entity ID , and Pathauto status. It looks like that was removed in D8.

Is there any other methods that could show the Pathauto state, like possibly a view that could be built?

Comment: The data is in the `key_value` table, with the type, e.g. `pathauto.node`, in the `collection` column, and the ID in the `name` column. There probably is a way to get that in Views but I don't know it

Comment: Thats where it was. I was able to export the data to a CSV file. Thank you so much for your help with this!